# Getting an HTTP 400 error from my API when testing via Postman

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, postman, rest

I developed an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Api and I always get the HTTP error 400 when testing it via POSTMAN.

When testing the API when is running in debug from Visual Studio, I get the error from POSTMAN while CURL command is getting an OK result.

[image: API running is IIS Express]

[image: POSTMAN HTTP 400 Error]

[image: CURL command]

I got the exact same result when running the API with the dotnet run command.

Is there something wrong with my POSTMAN configuration settings? Can someone help me fixing this issue please ?

Comment: Its saying 5 items in headers, try unchecking/removing them?

Comment: They are all unchecked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. I have to pass the Host header from POSTMAN.

[image: POSTMAN Host header]

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a "GET" request, try typing the URI to your browser instead. If you get the correct result it means that there is something wrong with your postman request parameters, maybe the headers. If the issue persists, try reading this https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/launching-postman/sending-the-first-request/